# My thunderbolt port on my 2011 MacBook Pro 17" stopped working

Tags: display, thunderbolt

Since day one through every os update I have used my MacBook hooked up to my tv as a source for playing movies. Out of the blue one day I hooked in the same thunderbolt to hdmi adapter that I had been using for 2 years or more and got nothing. Normally when I plug in the cable the MacBook screen would go black then both displays would come on. Now when I plug in the cable the MacBook flashes black for a split second really doesn't seem to go all the way off.

As a quick option I purchased a separate thunderbolt to hdmi adapter but it does the same thing. I felt like it may be some software deal or a setting but I really didn't want to dump everything and do a fresh install. Finally El Capitan came out and I was hoping that would fix the issue but still the same problem. I was running maverick when it happened out of the blue.

I have since tried to reset the smc and nvram